# Jooq for scala, how to create Converter for Option[Long]

Tags: scala, jooq, scala-2.12

I guess there is some issue with scala Long and java primitive long

```scala
class JooqOptionalLongConverter extends Converter[Long, Option[Long]] {
  override def from(databaseObject: Long): Option[Long] =
    Option(databaseObject)

  override def to(userObject: Option[Long]): Long = userObject match {
    case None       => null //  an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
    case None       => null
    case Some(long) => long
  }

  override def fromType(): Class[Long] = classOf[Long]

  override def toType: Class[Option[Long]] = classOf[Option[Long]]
}
```

It doesn't compile with exception

```
 an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
    case None       => null
```

Same approach for Option[String] works fine, but String is object...

this doesn't compile too

```scala
  private val optionalLongType = org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BIGINT.asConvertedDataType(new JooqOptionalLongConverter)
```

with message

```
overloaded method value asConvertedDataType with alternatives:
  [U](x$1: org.jooq.Binding[_ >: Long, U])org.jooq.DataType[U] <and>
  [U](x$1: org.jooq.Converter[_ >: Long, U])org.jooq.DataType[U]
 cannot be applied to ...
```

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Use `java.lang.Long` explicitly?

Comment: `scala.Long` depending on context will become `java.lang.Long` OR `long` to avoid boxing. Because of that you cannot pass there `null` because the language would try to have a primitive there.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

As it was mentioned in the comments, replacing [scala.Long](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Long.html) used as the first type parameter in `Converter` for [java.lang.Long](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) should be enough.

```scala
class JooqOptionalLongConverter extends Converter[java.lang.Long, Option[Long]] {
  override def from(databaseObject: java.lang.Long): Option[Long] =
    Option(databaseObject)

  override def to(userObject: Option[Long]): java.lang.Long = userObject match {
    case None       => null
    case Some(long) => long
  }

  override def fromType(): Class[java.lang.Long] = classOf[java.lang.Long]

  override def toType: Class[Option[Long]] = classOf[Option[Long]]
}
```

It could be easy to get confused which `Long` belongs to each `package`. Scala let you rename a class when you are [importing](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/packages-and-imports.html). Doing something like this, could help you to make it more readbale (this is a personal opinion).

```scala
import java.lang.{Long => JavaLong}

class JooqOptionalLongConverter extends Converter[JavaLong, Option[Long]] {
  // ... same for the other places where `java.lang.Long` is used
}
```

---

### Detailed answer

I haven't worked with [Jooq](https://www.jooq.org/). Based on the docs where it give details about how [Data type conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/) works, I guess you are trying to convert a **numeric nullable** column from a **table** to an `Option[Number]` in **scala**. There is an open issue with the title [Add support for Scala Option or Java Optional types](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3231).

That being said, the error shown by the compiler (`error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion`), is because how the [Type System](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) work in scala. There is a difference between what is a [value class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) and what is a [class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html)

The following diagram shows how the type hierarchies is designed.

[image]

We are going to focus in a couple of them:

- [Any](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/Any.html): is the root of the Scala class hierarchy. Every class in a Scala execution environment inherits directly or indirectly from this class.
- [AnyVal](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/AnyVal.html): is the root class of all **value types**, which describe values **not implemented as objects** in the underlying host system. Value classes are specified in Scala Language Specification.
- [AnyRef](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/AnyRef.html): is the root class of all **reference types**. All types except the value types descend from this class.
- [Null](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Null.html): is the type of the `null` literal. It is a subtype of every type except those of value classes. **Value classes** are subclasses of `AnyVal`, which includes primitive types such as `Int`, `Boolean`, and user-defined value classes.

---

As you can see, from the root you have a clear division between **values** (`AnyVal`) and **references** (`AnyRef`, which is analogue to [java.lang.Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) in Java). If you look at `Null`, you will see that it is a subtype of `AnyRef` but not a subtype of `AnyVal`.

So, when you are trying to do

```scala
  override def to(userObject: Option[Long]): Long = userObject match {
    case None       => null //  an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
    case Some(long) => long
  }
```

It's the same to do

```scala
val double: Double = null
val   long: Long   = null
val    int: Int    = null
val  short: Short  = null
```

All of them will give you the same compilation error due to `Null` is not a subtype of `AnyVal`.